# Can't convert 'Date' to 'int' in initialization as error

Tags: c++, class

I am trying default copying but I am getting this error:

> [Error] cannot convert 'Date' to 'int' in initialization
>   [Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

//Default copying

```
#include<iostream>
class Date{
    public:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

        void setday(int );
        void setmonth(int);
        void setyear(int);
};
void Date::setday(int d){
    day=d;}
    void Date::setmonth(int m){


    month=m;
}
void Date::setyear(int y){

    year=y;
}
int main(){
Date d1;
d1.setday(5);
d1.setmonth(6);
d1.setyear(7);
std::cout<<d1.day<<d1.month<<d1.year;
Date d2{d1};
std::cout<<d2.day<<d2.month<<d2.year;
return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Date d2{d1};
```

Uniform initialization is only available in C++11 and up, and it seems that your compiler uses C++03 by default. Add `-std=c++11` flag to your compilation (or update your compiler, GCC compiles with C++14 by default starting from GCC 6.1)

Eventually, you can use different forms of initialization:

```
Date d2(d1);
Date d2 = d1;
```

Comment: Or change `Date d2{d1}` to `Date d2(d1)`... or to `Date d2 = d1`...

Comment: @goodvibration Added. But it's better to upgrade compiler IMO ;)

Comment: What about using  ``unsigned char* localData = new unsigned char[42];
 memcpy( localData, pData, 42 );``